# JSF select many check box with Rich faces repeat/alignment

Tags: jsf

I am trying to create a custom Time chart where an activity can be toggled on or off for a specific time.

What I have right now is a table which looks like the following

```
names | Time1|time2|time3|time4|
______________________________
name1 | box box box box box box 
name2 | box box box box box box
```

what I want is the boxes to be correctly aligned with the corresponding time. So I wonder if you can break the selectManyCheckBoxes into different Columns?

where the code is

```
<table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>
                                <table class="times">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>12:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>01:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>02:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>03:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>04:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>05:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>06:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>07:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>08:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>09:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>10:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>11:00 AM</td>
                                        <td>12:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>01:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>02:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>03:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>04:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>05:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>06:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>07:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>08:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>09:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>10:00 PM</td>
                                        <td>11:00 PM</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <a4j:repeat value="#{scheduleNames}" var="scheduleName">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{scheduleName}" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h:selectManyCheckbox styleClass="styledGroup" value="#{schedules[scheduleName]}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="12:00 AM" itemValue="0" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="01:00 AM" itemValue="1" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="02:00 AM" itemValue="2" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="03:00 AM" itemValue="3" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="04:00 AM" itemValue="4" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="05:00 AM" itemValue="5" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="06:00 AM" itemValue="6" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="07:00 AM" itemValue="7" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="08:00 AM" itemValue="8" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="09:00 AM" itemValue="9" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="10:00 AM" itemValue="10" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="11:00 AM" itemValue="11" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="12:00 PM" itemValue="12" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="01:00 PM" itemValue="13" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="02:00 PM" itemValue="14" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="03:00 PM" itemValue="15" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="04:00 PM" itemValue="16" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="05:00 PM" itemValue="17" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="06:00 PM" itemValue="18" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="07:00 PM" itemValue="19" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="08:00 PM" itemValue="20" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="09:00 PM" itemValue="21" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="10:00 PM" itemValue="22" />
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="11:00 PM" itemValue="23" />
                                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </a4j:repeat>
                    </table>
```

and schedule is a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` renders by itself a `<table>`. So you end up with another `<table>` in a single `<td>` instead of having all items in separate `<td>`s.

Use `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` instead. First change `Map<String, List<Integer>>` property type to `Map<String, Boolean[]>` (and make sure that you prepare it with `new Boolean[24]`!). Then change the view as follows:

```
<td><label><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{schedules[scheduleName][0]}" /> 12:00AM</label></td>
<td><label><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{schedules[scheduleName][1]}" /> 13:00AM</label></td>
<td><label><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{schedules[scheduleName][2]}" /> 14:00AM</label></td>
<td><label><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{schedules[scheduleName][3]}" /> 15:00AM</label></td>
...
```

A `List<Integer>` is unsuitable because the value of `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` must be a `Boolean`. A `List<Boolean>` is clumsy because you need to fill it with 24 `Boolean.FALSE` entries beforehand to prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` problems. So, a `Boolean[]` should do.

```
schedules.put(scheduleName, new Boolean[24]);
// ...
```

and you can postprocess it back to `List<Integer>` as follows:

```
Boolean[] checkedHours = schedules.get(scheduleName);
List<Integer> hours = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < checkedHours.length; i++) {
    if (checkedHours[i]) {
        hours.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: the only reason I use a List<Integer> is because of when using selectManyCheckbox I can style it easy and add the actual value into a list. Quick question, how do you style it so it doesn't display a checkbox? I have a white/blue box that on click changes colors and I do not want to use the checkbox. It makes it easier for the user to see.

Comment: Use a shot of CSS/JS which hides the original checkbox and let the new element (span, div, etc) delegate the clicks to it. Several examples can be found in Google using keywords "css style checkbox".

Comment: okay, but i still can't hide the original checkbox. I have basically two boxes now. How are we suppose to hide the original JSF checkbox?

Comment: Just use CSS `display:none`. For future unrelated questions, please press `Ask Question` button on right top. Don't abuse the comments of different question for this.